# How to get the index in the 'in' statement in Python

Tags: python

I wrote an `if` statement like:

```
if word in vocab:
    print word
```

However, I also would like to know the matched `word` index in `vocab`.

Is there any way in Python can do this?

I just come up a solution that use `vocab.index(word)` to get the index, but this way go through the array twice (one in `if` statement, one call `index()`). I wonder there should be more efficiency method.

Thanks.

Comment: @sashkello not exactly the same, I would like to return the index using the 'in' keyword at the same time with if statement executing, and I also state the reason why I didn't choose the index() method.

Comment: @AbnerChou That is not possible, `in` returns only True or False. Also read about: [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary I saw use enumerate() in for statement could return both index and value, so I just would like to give it a try in if statement.

Comment: Suppose you had a way to do this. What are you going to do next with the information you have received? What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @AbnerChou The for-loop/enumerate based solution is going to be very very slow compared to `.index` and `.find` methods, and BTW you can easily get the value once you've the index.

Comment: @AbnerChou That question has multiple answers and they basically outline all you could possibly do.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just want to make it more efficiency. Suppose I have thousand words and I need to mapping them to another system, I need their index in both systems. However, if use 'in' and then call index() will cast too much time to do so. Why not there is a way that go through the list one time and return the indexes and matched values? The Christian answer is exactly what I want.

Comment: @sashkello thanks, I only look at the top answer. :)

Comment: "if use 'in' and then call index() will cast too much time to do so" you are over-thinking it. Unless you have a problem with performance, this is most likely not the place you would want to optimize. Have you profiled it? I'm sure the win is minuscule.

Comment: @sashkello not affect the performance when my dataset is small. but now my dataset is about 60000 words and 3180000 tokens, already take hours to perform. I'm just try to increase the program speed. otherwise, I have to use C++ or Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid one *loop*, you can use a `try-except` clause (without using `if ... in ...:`)

```
try:
    i = vocab.index(word)
except ValueError as e:
    print e # Optional
    i = -1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where I wish I could do assignment in an if statement, but I can't so this is the solution:

If `vocab` is a `list`:

```
try:
    index = vocab.index(word)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    print index, word
```

if `vocab` is a `str`:

```
index = vocab.find(word)
if index >= 0:
    print index, word
```

Comment: I assume it was because I used `index` and not `find`. One is for `list`, one is for `str`. I don't know what OP is using, but downvoter was expecting `find` (first version of answer only had `index`)

Comment: `index` works for strings just as well, just might not be as conveniant as `find` because of the exception. Anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: @tobias_k, thanks. I also preferred `find` for the reason of lack of exception. It's too bad there's no equivalent with a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
def getindex(iterable,target):
    for idx,value in enumerate(iterable):
        if value==target: return idx
    return -1
```

Note that this WILL NOT work if you're trying to find a substring in a string (as I'm assuming, since you're doing `if word in vocab`. In that case you really should do:

```
try: idx = iterable.index(target)
except ValueError as e: # Not found
    # Handle it
```

If you try to use the `getindex` function above, it will always return `-1` for any value `len(target) > 1` since it will break your iterable into its smallest iteration, which is by-letter for strings.

Comment: This is pretty much identical to the `index` function.

Comment: Sure is, but for some reason OP didn't seem to want to use `iterable.index(target)` so I thought I'd expose the `enumerate` function with a bit of an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at pythons [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

EDIT: Following with an example:

```
for i, j in enumerate(vocab):
if j == word:
    print (i, j)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Can you give an example of how enumerate would help? Simply referring to some external documentation isn't what this site is for.

Comment: Thanks, I know it work in 'for' statement, but in 'if' I got errors. Christian answer can solve my problem.